Why useRef not updating immediately?
I'm trying to set menuHeight depending on component FilterText or FilterCheckboxGroup. So i get height of those components and setting my state, first component updating correctly and i get for example 150 clientHeight, but i have problem with second component , first i get 220 clientHeight, but if manualy update page i get 320. It seems like useRef not updating immediately clientHeight of second component.
const [menuHeight, setMenuHeight] = useState()
const subMenuFilterList = useRef(null)

//adaptive menu height
useEffect(() => {
    if (subMenuFilterList.current && openSubMenu) {
        setMenuHeight(subMenuFilterList.current.clientHeight)
    } else {
        setMenuHeight(null)
    }
}, [openSubMenu, filterId])
 <Box
                        width={`${filterMenuSize}px`}
                        display={openSubMenu ? 'block' : 'none'}
                    >
                        {filtersList?.[filterId]?.sort === false && (
                            <Box>
                                {filtersList?.[filterId]?.systemName !==
                                'in'
                                    ? React.createElement(
                                          filtersList?.[filterId]?.node ??
                                              FilterText,
                                          {
                                              onChange,
                                              value,
                                              ...props,
                                              key: filterId,
                                              //   onKeyDown: e =>
                                              //       onkeyDownHadler(e),
                                              setOpenSubMenu:
                                                  setOpenSubMenu,
                                              setFilterValue:
                                                  setFilterValue,
                                              filtersList: filtersList,
                                              ref: subMenuFilterList,
                                          }
                                      )
                                    : React.createElement(
                                          filtersList?.[filterId]?.node ??
                                              FilterCheckboxGroup,
                                          {
                                              column: column,
                                              onChange,
                                              value,
                                              ...props,
                                              key: filterId,
                                              filtersList: filtersList,
                                              setOpenSubMenu:
                                                  setOpenSubMenu,
                                              setFilterValue:
                                                  setFilterValue,
                                              table,
                                              ref: subMenuFilterList,
                                          }
                                      )}
                            </Box>
                        )}
                    </Box>


It seems problem was on the side useRef and i decided to use ResizeObserver to observing and dynamically change height of my component.
useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
        for (let entry of entries) {
            const height = entry.contentRect.height
            setMenuHeight(height)
        }
    })

    if (subMenuFilterList.current) {
        observer.observe(subMenuFilterList.current)
    }

    return () => {
        if (subMenuFilterList.current) {
            observer.unobserve(subMenuFilterList.current)
        }
    }
}, [openSubMenu])

